# JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, object

What are the differences between these two codes in JavaScript?

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.X = 10;
obj.Y = 20;
```

And,

```
var obj = {X:10, Y:20};
```

Comment: Another important characteristic of the first case is that the 'Object' constructor gets called, while in the second case it doesn't.  At least that's the behavior in Firefox.

Comment: @opello: Really? How did you test that?

Comment: Technically, the Object constructor still gets called in the second case, but it will always use the built-in version. If you write your own Object function, it will get called in the first case, but not the second.

Comment: That's good to know.  I tested it by overwriting the Object function with something simple like: function(){alert('test');}

Comment: @opello: The ECMAScript spec says that using the object literal form will "Create a new object as if by the expression new Object().", which is somewhat open to interpretation as to what Object constructor should be used if the regular Object constructor visible to scripts has been replaced. The ECMAScript 5 spec is clearer: "Return a new object created as if by the expression new Object() where Object is the standard built-in constructor with that name."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing at all. Just syntax.

You could also use:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj["X"] = 10;
obj["Y"] = 20;
```

Answer (score 4):

The second is a shortcut for the first. Functionally they are the same.

Comment: Not necessarily a shortcut, but different syntax.  The second one is called JavaScript Object Notation, or JSON.

Comment: No, the second isn't JSON. JSON would be {"X":10, "Y":20}. The quoting is important.

Comment: Ah sorry, you are indeed correct.  Hm, what would it be called then?  Is it just 'shortcut object syntax?'

Comment: @opello It's called "object literal" syntax

Answer (score 1):

Object literal format `{}` was introduced with JavaScript 1.2, along with Array literal format `[]`.

So the more readable variant `{X:10, Y:20}` won't work in Netscape 3! (Oh no!)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really. Well, that's not quite true, but the differences are far too minor to mention.